# My program is not interpreting Geometrize JSON Shape Data correctly

Tags: python, json, turtle-graphics

For some reason, my program has the scale and rotation correct *atleast I think so* but the position is off. Here is the draw rectangle function. By the way, I only have rectangles in the json.

```
import turtle
import json

funnyTurtle = turtle.Turtle()

def drawRectangle(x, y, width, height, rotation, r, g, b, opacity):
    # Initialize turtle for rendering
    global funnyTurtle
    funnyTurtle.color(r, g, b)
    funnyTurtle.penup()
    funnyTurtle.goto(x, -y)
    funnyTurtle.pendown()
    funnyTurtle.setheading(-rotation)

    # Draw the rectangle
    for _ in range(2):
        funnyTurtle.forward(width)
        funnyTurtle.left(90)
        funnyTurtle.forward(height)
        funnyTurtle.left(90)
```

I tried searching everywhere on Google to see if anyone else was having the problem, or I was just parsing the JSON incorrectly. I found nothing. I tried many fixes such as inverting angles, inverting the position y-axis, and even tried asking ChatGPT to fix it. Nothing worked. I was expecting to see the shapes in the correct position.

Comment: `json` is unused here, so it's unclear what you're asking. Did you forget to post some of the code? Where's the JSON and what is the correct position you expect to see, exactly?

Comment: The json is being decoded but is not necessary for the actual interpretation of the code, but thanks for the question